# How to convert ASCII value to a character in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, ascii

I was wondering if anyone has the following php function equivalents in Objective-C for iPhone development:

1. ord() # returns the ASCII value of the first character of a string.
2. chr() # returns a character from the specified ASCII value.

Many thanks!

Comment: What happens if the string contains non ASCII characters?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

This is how you can work with ASCII values and `NSString`. Note that since `NSString` is working with unichars, there could be unexpected results for a non ASCII string.

```
// NSString to ASCII
NSString *string = @"A";
int asciiCode = [string characterAtIndex:0]; // 65

// ASCII to NSString
int asciiCode = 65;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", asciiCode]; // A
```

Answer (score 12):

```
//char to int ASCII-code
char c = 'a';
int ascii_code = (int)c;

//int to char
int i = 65; // A
c = (char)i;
```

Comment: char in c is a "smaller" int so you don't need to cast char to int

Comment: Thanks luvieere for the answer! Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, its worked for even negative value
e.g if int i = 223, then you get output of char c is -33