# How to generate random uppercase characters in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

How can I generate 20 Uppercase characters randomly in my Objective-C iOS app?

Comment: how about use ascii http://stackoverflow.com/a/2832750/926460

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`char c = (char)('A' + arc4random_uniform(25))`

Will give you a random uppercase character.

Comment: Shouldn't this be **arc4random_uniform(26)** ? As the highest number of arc4random_uniform(25) is 24 (according to the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html)) and 'A' + 24 is 'Y'.

Answer (score 0):

Store ALL uppercase Characters in array,And Generate Random numbers from 0-25,using rand() or arcg4rand(),then retrieve object ay random numbered index respectively.

Comment: Why would you bother will all the array manipulation when you can just do 'A' + your_random_number...

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", nil]; // You can add more uppercases here.
int firstRandom = objectAtIndex:arc4random()%[a count];
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [a objectAtIndex:firstRandom]];
[a removeObjectAtIndex:firstRandom];
// Avoiding some uppercase repetitions. ;-)
for (int i = 0; i < [a count]; i++) {
    int rndm = objectAtIndex:arc4random()%[a count];
    s += [a objectAtIndex:rndm];
    [a removeObjectAtIndex:rndm];
}
NSLog(@"%@", s);
[a release];
[s release];
```

Hope that answer this is what you want. :-)

Alberto