# Put Random Objects of NSArray To Random UIButtons Title of NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray, random-access

I have an Array with 26 Alphabets and Second Array with 3 UIButtons. I want to take random 3 Alphabets from the Array  and Set them randomly As a Titles of 3 UIButtons .here is code.

```
-(void)placeImages {
     NSMutableArray *alphabetarr=[[NSArray alloc]  
     initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",
     @"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z",nil];
     NSMutableArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btn1, btn2, btn3, nil];
     for (UIButton *btn in buttons) {
           int randomIndex= arc4random() % [alphabetarr count];
           NSString* titre = [alphabetarr objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
           [btn setTitle:titre forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
           [alphabetarr removeObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];                        
    }
```

Through using this code i seen only one alphet in one UIButton..please Suggest any one how Can I pick 3 random alphatbet from an Array and set these 3 random alphabets as Titles of 3 UIButtons of array.

Comment: See if you have allocated memories to buttons..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to generate random character. No need to set up an array for that.

```
char c = (char)('A' + arc4random_uniform(25))
```

[Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10561257/1249546).

Answer (score 1):

`removeObjectAtIndex:` is an `NSMutableArray` method, not `NSArray`'s. Change your `alphabetarr` type and the problem should go away.

Use the `rand()` or the `arc4random()` function for number generation. [Here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/random-thoughts-rand-vs-arc4random.html) you can see a comparison between the two.

Comment: Thanx for helping i edit code.but untill i am unable to get random alphbet to assign as a titles of uibuttons.

Comment: Are you sure btn1, bnt2... point to different button objects (that are at different coordinates)?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)placeImages {
 NSMutableArray *alphabetarr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]  
 initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",
 @"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z",nil];
 NSMutableArray *buttons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:btn1, btn2, btn3, nil];
 for (UIButton *btn in buttons) {
       int randomIndex= arc4random() % [alphabetarr count];
       NSString* titre = [alphabetarr objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
       [btn setTitle:titre forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
       [alphabetarr removeObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];                        
}
```

the allocation was of NSArray instead of NSMutableArray. this should work. hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: u can use random() also instead of arc4random()

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that you're overwriting the contents of the button text each time with a new letter. You'll want to save the previous text from the button and append the new character each time rather than resetting it with each new letter.

```
//gather random letter
NSString *titre = [alphabetarr objectAtIndex:randomIndex];

//gather current string
NSMutableString *currentString = [[btn titleLabel] text];

//append string
[currentString appendString:titre];

//set button text
[btn setTitle:currentString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

That should append a new letter to the button each time, rather than setting it to the last letter returned from the random array.

Hope that helps :)