# New Line or Carriage return iPad RTF Files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ms-word, rtf

I have an iPad app that creates Word Documents from data entered.

Originally i was using html word documents but these wont open in Pages.

I switch to using a RTF file which works for both.

I have a template where i replace sections of text like so:

```
[template replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"**DATE**" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",startDate] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [template length])];
```

I can replace the text fine and save as expected.

However the carriage return \n new line character is ignored. I have tried replacing the \n with \r \r\n and \par to no avail

What do i need to replace the carriage return so that it works once saved. Currently it is ignored.

Thank

Dan

Failure of that - a way to create Word documents that work on Both Pages and Word would be great

Comment: Edit* I am writing the in objective C

Answer (score 0):

In word \r and \n should be replaced by the ASCII characters 10 and 13. I'm not sure what language you are using, but chr(10) and chr(13) are likely candidates.

http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: I am writing in Objective C - what would I replace \n  with then?

Comment: I am not familiar with objective c, does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2832933/212940

Comment: Thanks but these still seem to not work for RTF files - anyother ideas

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for possible alternatives, there is a web service you can call ([Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com)) which provides the ability to create doc/rtf/other documents from Objective-C and stream back to the device (and/or email/store etc).  You need to be net-connected and happy with the external dependency but it can save you a lot of time (they have an Objective-C sdk).  Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Does the SDK enable you to download files direct to the iPad? Does the pricing increase with your users or do you have to pick a pricing group straight of?

Comment: Yes you can stream/download files directly to the ipad.  You'd have to contact them to ask how the pricing bands work.