# how to change ascii code to characters?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

how to change ASCII code to characters ? like '@#32' to 'space' and '@#46' to 'fullstops(.)'. I

am getting these sort of numbers from service and I need to convert them to characters.

But I am getting huge data from server and this data consists of number of '&#13' like

characters in it. Don't know how to get rid of all those terms.

When I used below code, its not working..

```
NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"] invertedSet];
NSString *resultString = [[description componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: What form are they `@#XX` or `&#XX`?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832729/how-to-convert-ascii-value-to-a-character-in-objective-c

Comment: @Volker hi, its not useful for me