# Objective-C how to convert a keystroke to ASCII character code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ascii, nsdictionary, lookup-tables

I need to find a way to convert an arbitrary character typed by a user into an ASCII representation to be sent to a network service. My current approach is to create a lookup dictionary and send the corresponding code. After creating this dictionary, I see that it is hard to maintain and determine if it is complete:

```
    __asciiKeycodes[@"F1"] = @(112);
    __asciiKeycodes[@"F2"] = @(113);
    __asciiKeycodes[@"F3"] = @(114);
//...
    __asciiKeycodes[@"a"] = @(97);
    __asciiKeycodes[@"b"] = @(98);
    __asciiKeycodes[@"c"] = @(99);
```

**Is there a better way to get ASCII character code from an arbitrary key typed by a user (using standard 104 keyboard)?**

Comment: Please checkout this answer, hopefully it helps a bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832729/how-to-convert-ascii-value-to-a-character-in-objective-c

Comment: In the view receiving the keyboard event override `keyDown(event: NSEvent)` and get the key code from the `keyCode` property of the event.

Comment: What do you plan to use for the letter "p"? That should be 112 but you are using that for the F1 key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective C has base C primitive data types. There is a little trick you can do. You want to set the keyStroke to a `char`, and then cast it as an `int`. The default conversion in c from a `char` to an `int` is that `char`'s ascii value. Here's a quick example.

`char character= 'a';
NSLog("a = %ld", (int)test);`

console output = `a = 97`
To go the other way around, cast an int as a char;

`int asciiValue= (int)97;
NSLog("97 = %c", (char)asciiValue);`

console output = `97 = a`

Alternatively, you can do a direct conversion within initialization of your int or char and store it in a variable.

`char asciiToCharOf97 = (char)97; //Stores 'a' in asciiToCharOf97`

`int charToAsciiOfA = (int)'a'; //Stores 97 in charToAsciiOfA`

Comment: Also, ascii is a standardized character set and doesn't include Function keys, your 112 would actually return a p, found this website to explain it and hopefully it will help you or lead you in the right direction if function keys are a must have for your project. [link](http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/re-ascii-code-for-functions-keys-f1-f12-and-tab-key.277457/)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for most keyboard keys, not sure about function keys and return key.

```
NSString* input = @"abcdefghijklkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+[]\{}|;':\"\\,./<>?~ ";
for(int i = 0; i<input.length; i ++)
{
    NSLog(@"Found (at %i): %i",i , [input characterAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Comment: @zaph This is the OP answering his own question.

Comment: What happened to "F1" from the question? The answer does not match the question.

Answer (score -1):

Use `stringWithFormat` call and pass the int values.

Comment: Try this: `NSString *obj = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c", 97];`